# Converting String to int in PHP

Tags: php, string, int

```
    $date = "1346706576967";  // miliseconds
    $newDate = (int) $date;
    echo $newDate;
```

I am getting "2147483647" as $newDate.

I simply want to convert the variable from String 1346706576967 to int 1346706576967 - how is this possible?

Comment: I have Godaddy hosting, how is this possible to change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2147483647 is the largest value an integer can hold unfortunately.  You could use a float here instead as a float can accurately hold integer values up to 10000000000000

Comment: Building on Will's answer, just use `    $date = "1346706576967";  // miliseconds
    $newDate = floatval($date);
    echo $newDate;`

Answer (score 2):

Because that is maximum size an integer in PHP can have.
You'll need a PHP library specific made for dealing with bigger integers like BCMath or GMP or just convert it to a float.

Answer (score 1):

possible conversions,

```
$input => 1346706576967
(integer)$input => 2147483647
intval($input) => 2147483647
$input*1 => 1346706576967
settype($input, "integer") => 1346706576967
```

http://phpconvert.com/online/

Answer (score 0):

You can use implicit conversion to convert it correctly:

```php
$date = "1346706576967";  // miliseconds
$newDate = 0+$date; // float(1346706576967)
$newDate = (int) $date; // int(2147483647)
```